# Understanding recursion in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, recurrence, induction

I'm really trying to wrap my brain around how recursion works and understand recursive algorithms. For example, the code below returns 120 when I enter 5, excuse my ignorance, and I'm just not seeing why?

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact(n-1)

answer = int (raw_input('Enter some number: '))

print fact(answer)
```

Comment: You will need to explain to us what exactly you don't understand. What do you think it should return?

Comment: Also, your indentation of your function is slightly off.

Comment: You see that inside `fact` that this same `fact` is called again? And that this selfcalling stops when n equals 0 ? And that by every selfcalling n gets one lower?

Comment: Thanks to all the great explanations. I will definitely practice everyday, as it seems indispensable to writing efficient algorithms.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

lets walk through the execution.

```
fact(5):
   5 is not 0, so fact(5) = 5 * fact(4)
   what is fact(4)?
fact(4):
   4 is not 0, so fact(4) = 4 * fact(3)
   what is fact(3)?
fact(3):
   3 is not 0, so fact(3) = 3 * fact(2)
   what is fact(2)?
fact(2):
   2 is not 0, so fact(2) = 2 * fact(1)
   what is fact(1)?
fact(1):
   1 is not 0, so fact(1) = 1 * fact(0)
   what is fact(0)?
fact(0):
   0 IS 0, so fact(0) is 1
```

Now lets gather our result.

```
fact(5) = 5* fact(4)
```

substitute in our result for fact(4)

```
fact(5) = 5 * 4 * fact(3)
```

substitute in our result for fact(3)

```
fact(5) = 5 * 4 * 3 * fact(2)
```

substitute in our result for fact(2)

```
fact(5) = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * fact(1)
```

substitute in our result for fact(1)

```
fact(5) = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * fact(0)
```

substitute in our result for fact(0)

```
fact(5) = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1 = 120
```

And there you have it. Recursion is the process of breaking a larger problem down by looking at it as successfully smaller problems until you reach a trivial (or "base") case.

Answer (score 11):

Break the problem down into its execution steps.

```
fact(5)
| 5  * fact(4)
|| 5 * (4 * fact(3))
||| 5 * (4 * (3 * fact(2))
|||| 5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * fact(1))))
||||| 5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * fact(0)))))
|||||| 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
120
```

Your function simply calls itself, just as any other function can call it. In this case however, your function needs a stopping point so that it doesn't infinitely recurse (causing a Stack Overflow!). In your case this is when `n` is 0 (it should probably be 1 instead).

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that each invocation of fact(), whether invoked externally or invoked by itself, gets its own distinct set of local variables.

```
fact(1) has n of 5
   fact(2) has n of 4
      fact(3) has n of 3
         fact(4) has n of 2
            fact(5) has n on 1
               fact(6) has n of 0
```

The deepest ones (here, `fact(6)` is deepest) are computed completely before the levels above them in the callstack are able to finish.

So

- `fact(6)` returns a 1 to `fact(5)` (termination case).
- `fact(5)` returns a 1 to `fact(4)` (1*1)
- `fact(4)` returns a 2 to `fact(3)` (2*1)
- `fact(3)` returns a 6 to `fact(2)` (3*2)
- `fact(2)` returns a 24 to `fact(1)` (4*6)
- and finally `fact(1)` returns 120 (5*24) to its caller, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive function is one that calls itself and continues to do so until evaluation is finished and a result is produced. The key with the factorial function you have above is the return x * fact(x-1)

So if you input 5 it will execute 5 * fact(5-1) * fact 4-1) .... And so on until it hits 0 and then returns 1. So you will have 5*4*3*2*1 which is 120.

It continues to allocate variables on the stack. So if you put a number that is too high it could result in a stack overflow exception. Unless you use something called tail call optimization (TCO) which turns the recursive function into a for loop and cleans up the memory allocated.