# Function call to self with return statement works ...but why?

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I am trying to get my head around Python having only really ever coded in Java in the past. I need some help understanding some code if someone can help, or point me in the direction of a good (simple) resource please?

I have written a Binary sort in Python from some pseudocode, it works but I don't understand how. The function would make sense to me if the code below didn't have a return statement on the line:

```
return findData( data, criteria, first, mid -1 )
```

Or if I set up a while loop and just modified the start or end index variable based on which half of the list I needed to reference.

But with this code I don't understand where the function is being returned to, or why the code fails if i remove them?? It makes sense that I return -1 as no match and 'mid' to reference the list position of a match, but the return statement passing data, criteria, first and last should surly cause a syntax error as there is no call to such a function?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can explain how what I have written works. My code is below.

Mr.D

```
# Binary Search

def findData( data, criteria, first, last ):

    if( last < first ):
        return -1

    else:
        mid = ( last + first ) // 2

        if( criteria == data[mid] ):
            return mid

        elif ( criteria > data[mid] ):
            print( "Currently looking at", data[mid], "in array poition", mid )
            return findData( data, criteria, mid +1, last )

        elif( criteria < data[mid] ):
            print( "Currently looking at", data[mid], "in array poition", mid )
            return findData( data, criteria, first, mid -1 )


Data = [15, 21, 29, 32, 37, 40, 42, 43, 48, 50, 60, 64, 77, 81, 90, 98]
Criteria = 98
Location = -1

Location = findData( Data, Criteria, 0, len( Data ) -1 )

if( Location < 0 ):
    print( Criteria, "is not located in the array." )
else:        
    print( Criteria, "is located in array position ", Location )
```

Comment: This is a recursive function

Comment: Wait, what exactly do you think should be a SyntaxError? You are just returning the result of a recursive call, which is the same as returning the result of calling any other function from the POV of syntax... IOW, I don't know what you mean by "but the return statement passing data, criteria, first and last should surly cause a syntax error as there is no call to such a function" What do you mean "there is no call to such a function", *the call is right there*.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693819/understanding-recursion-in-python) will clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for my tardy response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for my tardy response, I have had no internet for a couple of days due to the weather.
I don’t know why I said there should be a syntax error actually, as the number of variables past, and expected are correct. When I went through my original code it made no sense, so I modified it to look like what I posted. At the time, I had got myself in such a muddle I think I was still seeing the original code and not the amended code.
I will now look at the links posted and try and understand the logic of what is happening.
Thanks for you r help,
Mr.D

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function, therefore for the solution to converge to your solution (if it indeed does exist in the list, otherwise the function returns `-1`) it will need to continually call itself with it's current `data`, `criteria` and `first` (which have not changed since the first call to `findData()`) and it's new value of `last`. The new value of `last` is continually updated inside of the recursive function as either `mid+1` or `mid-1` until `criteria==data[mid]`, at which point the index of `criteria` is returned as `mid` and set to the variable `Location`.

Answer (score 0):

```python
return -1
```

This means evaluate the expression `-1` and return the result back as the result of this function.

```python
return mid + 1
```

This means evaluate the expression `mid + 1` and return the result back as the result of this function.

```python
return findData( data, criteria, first, mid -1 )
```

This means evaluate the expression `findData( data, criteria, first, mid -1 )`, which again means call the function `findData` with the evaluated arguments, and return  the result back as the result of this function. This does not return a function. You could actually split it up like this:

```python
Location = findData( data, criteria, first, mid -1 ) 
return Location
```

This is exactly the same. And the first line is exactly what you do to call the function in the first place.

Now if you call a function and do not use its return value it is dead code. Imagine this code:

```python
def test(n):
  somefun(n)

test(5) # ==> None
```

Now if you had returned the result of `somefun` then `test` would be an alias for `somefun`.

If you wanted to return a function you would not apply it by using the parens and argument:

```python
return findData    # returns a fucntion by name
return lambda v: v # return a lambda function
```

And of course. Recursive functions have no magic. As with all functions that call functions it waits for it to return to resume its own execution. The fact that the function that is called happens to be the same doesn't really matter. the bound parameters and local variables will be local to each call and thus they don't leak and each call return to the previous. No magic whatsoever. It could have been different functions that provided the same functionality each time.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I think I should have come back to my code after taking a break. When I look at it now, everything seems to make sense, apart from my question. Sorry to have got myself in a knot and asked such a strange question!

Comment: @Mr__D 20 years after learning my first programming language I started learning lisp and one of the exercises is to create an interpreter.  Asking questions are the way to go instead of randomly accepting and move on. Knowing how languages work makes you a better programmer. Every programner should try making their own language. You get new respect for people like Rossum.

Comment: Hello again,
Having come back from lunch with the in-laws, I decided to have another look at my code. It has been bothering me all afternoon why I posted a question, when I could clearly see and follow the logic of the code for myself.

Comment: I have now got to the bottom of this mystery, and I am still in need of help. I wrote several search and sort algorithms that night from pseudocode, and while trying to understand one, got myself in a knot, named it incorrectly, and then posted a similar one (that I understood) to the forum.
I don’t want to adjust my original question, (well I do!) but that would make the responses inaccurate. I have therefore posted a second question in hope that those of you that responded to this one, will have a look at my ‘actual query’.  
Thanks Mr__D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098645/recursive-method-has-no-return-statement-yet-seems-to-return-a-value-in-python